# Collection View With Variable Cell Size That Fills The Width of the view

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to know if it is possible to make a `UICollectionView` that has a variable cell width where there are 2 possible types of cells,

- one kind where it takes up 1/4th of the iPads screen and
- another that takes up half.

I want it to be that if there is a 1/4th cell and then a 1 half cell I can make it so there is a 1/4th cell at the end to make sure the width of the display is filled up. Or if there are 3 1/4th cells I can tell it to shown another 1/4th cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in a collection view the cells can be all different sizes.  For example: [image]

Comment: I understand that but if I have different width cells can I make sure the cells for each row fill the width of the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you have already answered your question but to make sure your cells fill the width of the iPad you just have to implement your own CollectionViewLayout. You just have to implement your management rules into the `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. Just compute the attributes size and frame.

You can overload `UIFlowLayout` if you want things to be even easier and if your layout is not too complicated.